# Using gif image and saving

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I tried to add gif image into a canvas and after adding, gif was static but when I change  some other object property, i.e. `Kinetic.Text();`s `setY()` property, gif image moved to another step of an animation.

Is any way, how to to add **gif image** into a *layer* and then use

```
stage.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl) {
        //callback
    })
});
```

to save as a gif image? Or does exist any different mechanism how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the first image in an animated .gif you can draw it to an offscreen canvas and then use `context.getDataURL` to get a dataUrl of the first image:

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/53Jw4/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/animated.gif";
    function start(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var url=canvas.toDataURL();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>The animated .gif in an img element</h4>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/animated.gif"><br>
    <h4>The animated .gif drawn in a canvas element</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this solution looks good but my project is implemented by KineticJS, and I add objects like( images, text) by adding into the `layer` - `var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();`. The weirdest thing is whenever I change any property of any object(move text, change text...) the animation of gif will change by one step.

Comment: Even if your project is implemented in KineticJS, you can always use a regular html canvas element to capture a dataURL of the first image in your animated .gif (nothing illegal about using other resources to solve problems!).  And yes, that KineticJS behavior is weird--although KineticJS does not support animated .gifs so I'm not quite sure what I would expect.  Cheers! :-)

Comment: yes, using other method to add elements to canvas is the best solution. And saving gif as an animation, I guess, is not possible using canvas. Am I right?

Comment: Oh...you mean "playing" a .gif as a series of images?  Sure, that's do-able!  shachaf has written a .gif parser that you can use to get each image in an animated gif: https://github.com/shachaf/jsgif

Comment: Thanks for linking this library. It will be very useful for me:) thanks